# act_as_votable rails Counting votes on answers emited by specific user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am close to new at Ruby on Rails (but love it) and I cannot managge to filter acuratelly.

Mi goal is to retrieve all the votes puted on answers created by one user. And I am using act_as_votable_gem

On answer.rb I have:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable    
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :letter
  ...
end
```

At user.rb I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter 
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

At users_controller.rb comes the trick because I have the letter form on the user show action:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])  
  @letter = Letter.new(params[:letter])   
  @letters = @user.letters.all
  @answers = @user.answers
  ...
  @emitedupvotes = @user.votes.up.count
  @emiteddownvotes = @user.votes.down.count
  @totalemitedvotes = @emitedupvotes + @emiteddownvotes
  @receivedupvotes = ????????
  @receiveddownvotes = ???????
  ...
end
```

I have tryed:

a) (the recomended one) @receivedupvotes = @answer.votes.up.count but this one needs @answer = Answer.find(params[:id]) and I am having => "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /users/1 Couldn't find Answer with id=1"

Or, if I do: Answer.find(params[:answer_id]) => "Couldn't find Answer without an ID".

b) (the most logical) @receivedupvotes = @answers.votes.up.count => "undefined method `votes' for nil:NilClass"

c) (crazy one) @receivedupvotes = @answers.user.votes.up.count => "undefined method `user'"

d) @receivedupvotes = @answers.votes.up.where("voter = @user").count => "undefined method `votes' for nil:NilClass".

So, I tryed joins (never done before):

e) @receivedupvotes = @answers.joins(:votes).votes.up.count => "undefined method `votes' for..."

f) @receivedupvotes = @answers.joins(:votes).up.count => "undefined method `up' for..."

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still stuck on this, but if so..

What gets voted on? Seems like Answer gets voted on.

If User has_many :answers, then that means @user.answers will return you an array of Answer objects. However, judging by your point b) it looks like @answers is nil, so you'll have to dig into that to find out why.

So getting @user.answers to return an actual array of Answer and not nil is your first step.

Once you get that far, @answers.votes won't work because again, @answers is an array. Each Answer has votes, so you would call votes on an instance of Answer, not on the array.

Getting back to your main goal which is to tally up all the up and down votes a user received. Since User doesn't get voted on, but Answer does get voted on, you'll want to tally up all the votes for each of the user's answers.

Here's one way:

```
@receivedupvotes = 0
@receiveddownvotes = 0
@user.answers.each do |answer|
    @receivedupvotes = @receivedupvotes + answer.votes.up
    @receiveddownvotes = @receiveddownvotes + answer.votes.down
end
```

Also, you should really use underscores in your variable names, like @received_up_votes. It's the recommended way for Ruby and is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff. Thank you very much. It is working now as it should.

This is the answer for others to read:

@user.answers is working as it should.

An this is the working implementation for counting votes on user answers with act_as_votable:

```
@user_answers_received_upvotes = 0
@user_answers_received_downvotes = 0
@user.answers.each do |answer|
    @user_answers_received_upvotes = @user_answers_received_upvotes + answer.votes.up.size
    @user_answers_received_downvotes = @user_answers_received_downvotes + answer.votes.down.size
end           
@user_answers_total_received_votes = @user_answers_received_upvotes + @user_answers_received_downvotes
```

I will upvote your answer when I can.

Thanks again.